# Qual é mais eficiente, realizar várias queries ou usar JOIN?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, desempenho, join

Tenho uma tabela `X` que possui os dados do meu usuário, e preciso retornar para o cliente os dados relacionados a esse usuário na tabela `Y` e `Z`.
Posso fazer isso usando `JOIN` ou:

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM Y WHERE X_id = id
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM Z WHERE X_id = id
```

Qual é mais eficiente?

Comment: Eu já fiz uma consulta dessas em um cenário muito específico que ficou mais rápido sendo várias seleções. Foi fazendo uma estrutura de dados para otimizar o resgate desejado, não soube passar para a engine de banco as dicas para ele fazer a consulta rapidamente (Litebase à época). Depois de uns 3, 4 anos, mesmo mudando para SQLite estava mais eficiente separado, mas a manutenção estava muito complicada a propensa a bugs. Então uni tudo em uma consulta só.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depende do banco de dados, depende dos dados constantes nas tabelas, depende da configuração da tabela, depende de outros fatores específicos.

Pode ser que seja igual, pode ser que o `JOIN` seja mais rápido porque ele tem mais condições de otimizar, mas pode ser que ele acabe fazendo algumas operações por ter uma relação que não seriam feitas na consulta separada.

Não tem como responder isso a não ser dizer que tem que medir para seu caso específico com os dados atuais. E pode mudar no futuro. Um banco de dados é um mecanismo cheio de otimizações para o caso.

Se eu tiver que chutar eu diria que o `JOIN` será mais rápido, mas não confio em chutes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Acho que a melhor solução seria agrupar tudo em uma única consulta:

```
SELECT Y.*, Z.*
FROM X
JOIN Y on Y.id = X.id 
JOIN Z on Z.attr1 = Y.attr1
WHERE X.id = @id
```

Você poderia remover a tabela *X* do join e usar de um *subselect*, mas acredito que a solução acima tem melhor performance, já que não repete *selects* para a comparação do *X.id*.

Answer (score 0):

Cada SQL (select) será executado uma vez, enviado (rede) ao banco de dados, criado um contexto para a query e retornado o resultado(rede de novo).

Pensando nesse fluxo sendo executado milhares de vezes, o JOIN é mais eficiente. Na verdade, um único SQL tende a ser mais eficiente para as consultas pequenas.

Quando o SQL fica muito grande, aí as coisas mudam e pode ser melhor quebrar em pedaços.

Quando o assunto é banco de dados e performance, o caminho é pesquisar, buscar as melhores práticas, mas nada evita os testes. Se tem dois caminhos possíveis, testes os dois e veja os resultados.